# Javascript media queries not working in safari / iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, safari, media-queries

Hope someone can help.

The following lines of code work in everything except Safari.

```
 if(window.matchMedia('(resolution:320dpi)').matches){res = i;}
 if(window.matchMedia('screen and (resolution:320dpi)').matches){wkres = I;}
```

Has anyone else discovered how to get Safari to recognise / process these queries?
Any and all help gratefully received.

Comment: https://caniuse.com/?search=resolution seems to think it is using the -webkit- prefix, but that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Safari [does not support `resolution`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/resolution#browser_compatibility), though it looks like the relevant bug [has been fixed](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=78087) so it'll come out at some point in a Safari release.

It does support [`window.devicePixelRatio`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/devicePixelRatio#browser_compatibility), though, which tells you the ratio of device pixels to [CSS pixels](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/CSS_pixel) (96ths of an inch).

So for the resolution part of that, you can use something along these lines:

```
const is320dpiOrMore = (window.devicePixelRatio * 96) >= 320;
```

Answer (score 0):

As it says above, Safari [does not support matchMedia resolution](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/resolution#browser_compatibility), but it supports the non-standard [-webkit-device-pixel-ratio](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/-webkit-device-pixel-ratio)

```
/* A unit of "dppx" is implied: */
@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) { ... }
/* ... is equivalent to: */
@media (min-resolution: 2dppx) { ... }

/* Similarly: */
@media (-webkit-max-device-pixel-ratio: 2) { ... }
/* ... is equivalent to: */
@media (max-resolution: 2dppx) { ... }
```